# Ion.RangeSlider color from middle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I'm trying to use `Ion.RangeSlider` to make a slider where the color starts from the center and goes in the direction of the slider control until it hits the slider control. Right now, this is what I have:

[image: Current Slider (color goes from left end to slider control)]

Instead, I would like the color to go from the center of the slider to the slider control.

[image: How I want it to be]

How can I make the `RangeSlider` work like that so that the color starts from the middle (as shown above)?

#### EDIT:

I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28361916/ion-rangeslider-2-0-3/29072577#29072577), but it deals with sliders with two controls instead one.

#### EDIT 1:

**`setup.js`**:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

     $(".slider").each(function() {

        console.log($(this).attr("id"));
        $(this).ionRangeSlider({
            type: $(this).attr("data-slider_type"),
            grid: $(this).attr("data-slider_grid"),
            min:  $(this).attr("data-slider_min"),
            max:  $(this).attr("data-slider_max"),
            prefix: $(this).attr("data-slider_prefix")+" ",
            postfix: " " + $(this).attr("data-slider_suffix"),
            step: $(this).attr("data-slider_stepper"),
            from:  $(this).attr("data-slider_from")
        });

        $(this).on("change", function () {
            var $this = $(this),
                value = $this.prop("value").split(";");
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: Can you provide code?

Comment: @JordanS I'm using the Special Fields extension for the Gravity Forms plugin for WordPress. It automatically uses `Ion.RangeSlider` when it generates sliders. I want to change the default slider coloring behavior. I've included the `setup.js` file that creates the sliders, if that helps.

Comment: https://github.com/jordansoltman/ion.rangeSlider is a fork I've made that adds an additional boolean option "fixMiddle" which is the behavior that you are looking for. Please note that I didn't minify my changes so you'll have to use ion.rangeSlider.js or minify it yourself. All of the changes I made are here: https://github.com/jordansoltman/ion.rangeSlider/commit/63afea724e7f8dab527cd70524535f951d6b8d41#diff-91cc6fde25fe380ac2a7ac58e1538dce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use: https://github.com/jordansoltman/ion.rangeSlider with has the additional boolean option: fixMiddle. For example:

```
$(".slider").ionRangeSlider({
    fixMiddle: true,
    ...
});
```

**Note: use ion.rangeSlider.js as ion.rangeSlider.min.js has not been updated.**

Comment: Thanks for changing the JS to support that! I used your new version and it works perfectly. Could you submit a PR back to the main repo so that it gets merged into the next version of rangeSlider?

Comment: I'm not sure that it's a common enough use case that they will accept it, but I can try.

Comment: While the change worked great, im running into a issue. Hopefully you can help. If the user goes to the next page of the multi-page form, then clicks on the previous button to go back to the slider page -> the slider values they inputted gets lost. Sliders go back to the middle value. 

How can i fix this? 

Thanks